# Cannot add pagination to my angular project

Tags: angular, pagination, mat-table

I have tried all the things I know but with no success. I want to add pagination to a covid-19 table. The paginator shows how much rows are in the table but it is not splitting them into pages.

Here is the code I've done.

Here is my `component.ts`:

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, HostListener, OnInit, ViewChild, } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Countries, sortData } from '../app.model';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { DataTableDataSource } from './data-table-datasource';
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger, } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-data-table',
    templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('detailExpand', [
            state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
            state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
            transition(
                'expanded <=> collapsed',
                animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')
            ),
        ]),
    ],
})
export class DataTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator!: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
    @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable<Countries>;
    @ViewChild('paginator', { read: MatPaginator }) paginatorlist: MatPaginator;
    dataSource: DataTableDataSource;
    filter: sortData = new sortData();

    /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
    displayedColumns = [];
    scrWidth: any;
    constructor(public appService: AppService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new DataTableDataSource(this.appService);
        this.sortData(false);
        this.setupTable();
        this.getScreenSize();
    }

    sortData(isChange: boolean) {
        if (isChange) {
            this.filter.pageSize = this.paginator.pageSize;
            this.filter.pageNumber = this.paginator.pageIndex + 1;
            // this.filter.sortColumn = this.sort.active;
            // this.filter.sortDirection = this.sort.direction;
            console.log(this.paginator.pageIndex);
        } else {
            this.filter.pageSize = 15;
            this.filter.pageNumber = 1;
            // this.filter.sortColumn = 'todayCases';
            // this.filter.sortDirection = 'true';
            // console.log(this.filter);
        }
        this.dataSource.loadData(this.filter);
        (error) => console.error(error);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
}
```

Here is my `datasource.ts`:

```js
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { finalize, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiResponse, Countries, sortData } from '../app.model';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';

export class DataTableDataSource extends DataSource<Countries> {
    
    public dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Countries[]>([]);
    private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();
    private totalDataCountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    public totalDataCount$ = this.totalDataCountSubject.asObservable();
    paginator: MatPaginator;
    sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private appService: AppService) {
        super();
    }

    loadData(filter: sortData) {
        this.appService
            .getData(filter)
            .pipe(finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)))
            .subscribe((data: any) => {
                // console.log(data.response);
                if (data) {
                    this.totalDataCountSubject.next(data.length);
                    this.dataSubject.next(data);
                    console.log(data.length);
                }
            });
    }

    connect(): Observable<Countries[]> {
        return this.dataSubject.asObservable();
    }

    disconnect(): void {
        this.dataSubject.complete();
        this.totalDataCountSubject.complete();
        this.loadingSubject.complete();
    }
}
```

And here is my `HTML`:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 data-table">
    <table mat-table multiTemplateDataRows class="full-width-table" matSort matSortActive="todayCases" matSortDirection="asc"
        aria-label="Elements" [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <!-- Country Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Country</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.country }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cases">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Cases</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.cases }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Active</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.active }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="todayCases">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Today Cases</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.todayCases }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="todayDeaths">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Total Deaths</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.todayDeaths }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container class="recovered" matColumnDef="recovered">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Recovered</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.recovered }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="dataSource.totalDataCount$ | async" [pageSize]="15" [pageSizeOptions]="[15, 20, 25]">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have checked your `StackBlitz`. In the `DataUrl` you are not passing any query string parameter for `pageSize` and `pageNumber`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have to set the **total available data length** to the `pageSize` parameter of the `paginator`.

For example, you have **30** countries' data and your `pageSize` is **10**. So, you have to set the `pageSize` parameter of the `paginator` to **30** and your visible data will be **10**.

I've mocked your `AppService` with static data. And showed how to populate data for pagination.

And you also missed filtering data after change of `pageSize` or `page`. I've also done that.

Observe the demo and you'll be able to understand.

Working solution created at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x9kduc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I get the logic but for fixed data :), I'm still a rookie. here is my  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gruugp?file=src/app/app.service.ts)

Comment: Check out the latest StackBlitz link in the answer.

Comment: it's not loading any data

Comment: You solved my problem! Thanks a million! You are a savior!

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Api end doesn't support data paging. It is returns all data even if you request with `pageSize` and `pageNumber` parameters in query string.

The solution is to page the data on client side. The data source type you are using currently (`DataSource<T>`) will add more complexity in client side data paging scenario. You should use the `MatTableDataSource<T>` as the data-source - it has automatic data paging support once you feed it all the data.

Following is a modified/simplified version of your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gruugp?file=src/app/app.service.ts) that you can try -

Component code -

```js
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator!: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Countries[]>([]);
    displayedColumns = ['country', 'cases', 'active', 'todayDeaths', 'recovered'];
    filter: sortData = new sortData();

    constructor(public appService: AppService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        this.filter.sortColumn = 'country';
        this.filter.sortDirection = 'asc';
        this.appService.getData(this.filter).subscribe(
            p => {
                this.dataSource.data = p;
            },
            e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
}
```

In the Template code only remove the `length` binding from the `mat-paginator` -

```html
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="15" [pageSizeOptions]="[15, 20, 25]"> </mat-paginator>
```

This should be enough to make your pagination work. You don't need to use the `DataTableDataSource`.